# Vue.js + Dexie: import as a module with custom functions

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, dexie

I've got a working Vue.js with a Dexie IndexedDB database, working smoothly like this:
Wherever in Vue I need to access the database I import the module:

```
import db from '@/services/MyIdb'
```

And I can access the Dexie methods directly, like for example:

```
db.table(tableName).clear()
```

The module, `MyIdb.js` is set up like this (I removed some code and tables to simplify):

```
    import Dexie from 'dexie'

    const db = new Dexie('myDatabase')
    const idb_schema_old = { myTable: '&key', }
    const idb_schema = { myTable: '&key', }
    const db_version_old = 9
    const db_version = 10

    // NEW VERSION
    db.version(db_version_old).stores(idb_schema_old)
    db.version(db_version).stores(idb_schema)

    db.open().then(function(){
        // Success
    }).catch(Dexie.UpgradeError, function (e) {
        // Failed with UpgradeError
        console.error ("Upgrade error: " + e.message)
        console.log("Dropping database and installing latest version")
        db.delete()
        db.version(db_version).stores(idb_schema)
        db.open().catch(function (err) {
            console.error (err.stack || err);
        })

    }).catch(Error, function (e) {
        // Any other error derived from standard Error
        console.error ("Error: " + e.message);
    }).catch(function (e) {
        // Other error such as a string was thrown
        console.error (e);
    });

    export default db;
```

All good. But, now I'd like to be able to call the initialisation from an arbitrary point in the program (there's a button to drop and reload the database). Thus, something like this:

```
    import Dexie from 'dexie'

    const db = new Dexie('myDatabase')
    const idb_schema_old = { myTable: '&key', }
    const idb_schema = { myTable: '&key', }
    const db_version_old = 9
    const db_version = 10

    init() {
        // NEW VERSION
        db.version(db_version_old).stores(idb_schema_old)
        db.version(db_version).stores(idb_schema)

        db.open().then(function(){
            // Success
        }).catch(Dexie.UpgradeError, function (e) {
            // Failed with UpgradeError
            console.error ("Upgrade error: " + e.message)
            console.log("Dropping database and installing latest version")
            db.delete()
            db.version(db_version).stores(idb_schema)
            db.open().catch(function (err) {
                console.error (err.stack || err);
            })

        }).catch(Error, function (e) {
            // Any other error derived from standard Error
            console.error ("Error: " + e.message);
        }).catch(function (e) {
            // Other error such as a string was thrown
            console.error (e);
        });
    }

    export default db;
```

The initialisation is now a function, which I'd like to call as something like db.init().
The code above is wrong and doesn't work. But how to implement something like this, where I could call the function like `db.init()` or `something.init()`

Throughout my program I already `import db` and call Dexie methods, I'd prefer not to have to rewrite all that.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code is a misinterpretation of how Dexie deals with upgrades. You do not have to catch UpgradeError and reinitialize the database. You simply declare the version you use and Dexie will upgrade the database if needed. In Dexie 3, you also do not need to keep old versions of the schema in your code, see [Version handling](https://dexie.org/docs/Tutorial/Design#database-versioning).

You seem to need an action to delete and recreate the database. This should be done using [Dexie.delete()](https://dexie.org/docs/Dexie/Dexie.delete()) followed by a new call to [db.open()](https://dexie.org/docs/Dexie/Dexie.open()). You can also use [Table.clear](https://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.clear()) on all tables, but autoincremented keys would not be reset and there's no way to change schema in that operation.

```js
async function recreateDatabase(db) {
  await db.delete();
  await db.open();
}
```

Here's also a [jsitor sample](https://jsitor.com/IezMBCaDJ) that does db.delete() followed by db.open().

Comment: Just checked my package.json, seems I'm at version 2.0.4. I hadn't noticed that v3 existed yet! Aside from that I may not need this anymore when migrating to v3, the question was how to add your own functions to the/a vuejs module like Dexie.